# Excel export issue(french description)

Tags: export-to-excel

```
try
{
    //Start Excel and get Application object.
    oXL = new Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = false;
    oXL.UserControl = false;
    //Get a new workbook.
    oWBook = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open(strFilename, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false));
    oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWBook.ActiveSheet;
    oSheet.Activate();

    //Create header row 2
    oXL.ReferenceStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1;
    Excel.Range oRange2 = oSheet.get_Range("A2", "A2");
    oRange2.FormulaR1C1 = HeaderLine1;

    //Create header row 2
    oRange2 = oSheet.get_Range("A3", "A3");
    oRange2.FormulaR1C1 = HeaderLine2;

    oRange2 = oSheet.get_Range("A" + StartRowNumber.ToString().Trim(), Missing.Value);
    var temp = oSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" + TextFileName, oRange2, Missing.Value);

    temp.Name = TextFileName.ToUpper().Replace(".TXT", "");
    temp.PreserveFormatting = true;
    temp.AdjustColumnWidth = false;
    temp.TextFileStartRow = 1;
    temp.TextFileParseType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited;
    temp.TextFileTextQualifier = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote;
    temp.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = false;
    temp.TextFileTabDelimiter = true;
    temp.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = false;
    temp.TextFileCommaDelimiter = false;
    temp.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = false;
    temp.TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|";
    temp.TextFilePlatform = 1252;//65001;//1252;//65001;//1200;
    //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page
    temp.TextFileColumnDataTypes = GetDataType(ColumnDataType);
    temp.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = true;
    temp.Refresh(false);

    //temp.Connection.ToString();
    temp.Delete();

    oXL.ReferenceStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1;
    oWBook.Save();
    oWBook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    oWBook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
}
finally
{
    oXL.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet);
    oSheet = null;
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWBook);
    oWBook = null;
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);
    oXL = null;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Comment: If you don't tell us what the issue is, we can't help you. Take a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: 0down votefavorite
1
 



I am exporting data to excel file using Excel query table. There will be a text file with the data containing many rows, each cell is separated by | character. I am dumping the data to excel file using the code given above       When the text file contains some special characters( Ex French words) it will not display as they are when the excel file is opened after generating